# My body arrive null in my backend when mapping to the model(axios/vue.js/c#)

Tags: c#, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to send my vue data to my backend and map it to the FilterModel and it's always null, whatever I tried I was ending up with null : this is the console.log result you see in getFilteredLogs :

```
{
    "searchQuery": "e",
    "dateTimeRange": {},
    "logTypeFilter": {
        "error": false,
        "warning": false,
        "critical": false
    }
}
```

I tried mapping to just `LogTypeFilter` which is part of `FilterModel` and it worked I received 3 Booleans value for error, warning and critical.

I thought maybe it was the dates, but I even tried hardcoding dates or changing them to string and it didn't do anything.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot.

**I have this data in my vue component which is the complex object I am trying to send to my backend:**

```
data() {
    return {
          filterModel:{
            searchQuery: '',
            dateTimeRange:{
                sartDateTime: Date,
                endDateTime: Date
            },
            logTypeLevel:{
              error: false,
              warning: false,
              critical: false
            }
          }
    }
}
```

**This is my call to my backend :**

```
getFilteredLogs(filterModel) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(filterModel))
      return client.post(
           '/logs/filter', {
               headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
               body: JSON.stringify(filterModel)
           }
      )
}
```

**This is my controller code in the back end where the FilterModel is null (note I added [FromBody] just to try it out, didn't change anything) :**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("filter")]
public IActionResult FilterLogs([FromBody] FilterModel filter)
{
     return Ok(_logLogic.FilterLogs(filter));
}
```

**This is my model (added serializable just try out, didn't change anything) :**

```
[Serializable]
public class FilterModel
{
      public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
      public DateTimeRange DateTimeRange { get; set; }
      public LogTypeFilter LogTypeFilter { get; set; }
}
    
[Serializable]
public class DateTimeRange
{
      public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
      public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
    
[Serializable]
public class LogTypeFilter
{
       public bool Critical { get; set; }
       public bool Error { get; set; }
       public bool Warning { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check the model state and see if there's any errors. It's probably because `''` isn't a valid `DateTime` and you spelt `StartDateTime` as `sartDateTime`.

Comment: Also you have `LogTypeFilter` in your backend model but `logTypeLevel` (should be `logTypeFilter`) in your client model

Comment: @Shoejep Sorry i just changed ' ' to Date as it was before, i still had ' ' from the time i tried sending a string haha from front end and change to string in backend also and that didn't change anything. I changed it back to Date in the code above, also corrected typo and nothing changed, it's really weird haha.

Comment: @Ibsn Corrected that mistake, i am still getting null :( it's really weird cause when i am in front end the object is good, but when it arrives in backend the 3 items in FilterModel : searchQuery dateTimeRange & logTypeFilter are null

Comment: Look in the `ModelState`, it should tell you what's not working.

Comment: @Shoejep i am a bit confused when you tell me to check ModelState, you want me to just create a vrariable like var state = ModelState or just do a if(ModelState.IsValid) in my code ? I tried doing that and isValid is true but the count of model state is 0 so i am a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: Normally that would contain the errors as to why it's null. I'll post an answer soon as to why yours isn't working.

Comment: @Shoejep sweet thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue your code isn't working is because of your `axios` post. It wasn't sending the body of the post at all. You can diagnose this in the future by looking at the payload section of a request in the browser network tab of the developer tools. e.g. in the image below, you can see it's sending the headers in post body.

[image]

You can also see on [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) that there's no method that supports `axios.post` that sends the config as the second parameter and the data as the third parameter.

Below is the working solution with controller and html file that I used to reproduce your issue.

**LogController.cs**

```
namespace TestApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LogsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("filter")]
        public IActionResult FilterLogs([FromBody] FilterModel filter)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class FilterModel
    {
        public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
        public DateTimeRange DateTimeRange { get; set; }
        public LogTypeFilter LogTypeFilter { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DateTimeRange
    {
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LogTypeFilter
    {
        public bool Critical { get; set; }
        public bool Error { get; set; }
        public bool Warning { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.25.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-/Q6t3CASm04EliI1QyIDAA/nDo9R8FQ/BULoUFyN4n/BDdyIxeH7u++Z+eobdmr11gG5D/6nPFyDlnisDwhpYA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script>
            new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                data() {
                    return {
                        filterModel: {
                            searchQuery: "Test",
                            dateTimeRange: {
                                startDateTime: new Date(),
                                endDateTime: new Date()
                            },
                            logTypeFilter: {
                                error: false,
                                warning: false,
                                critical: false
                            }
                        }
                    };
                },
                mounted() {
                    this.getFilteredLogs(this.filterModel);
                },
                methods: {
                    getFilteredLogs(filterModel) {
                        return axios.post("/logs/filter", this.filterModel, 
                        {
                                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```